# Guardar en un ArrayList los documentos obtenidos en una coleccion usando Firestore y Java

Tags: java, firebase

Buenas noches a tod@s,

estoy tratando de almacenar en un arraylist todos los documentos obtenidos tras realizar un Get a mi coleccion Rutinas que tengo en una base de datos Firestore.

Tengo declarada la variable ArrayList lista Rutinas;
he realizado la prueba dentro del metodo donde obtendo todos los documentos de mi coleccion, y puedo comprobar en el Log que obtengo los documentos pasandolos a un objeto tipo Rutina y mostrandolos usando el metodo toString que esta implementado en mi clase Rutina.
Posteriormente intento añadir esa rutina en mi ArrayList pero tras hacerle un .size siempre me da como resultado 0.

Creo que no es posible añadir en un arraylist nada dentro del metodo
rutinasRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

```
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot rutina: task.getResult()){
```

Ya que tambien he probado a insertar una rutina desde fuera y si que lo añade.

Haber si tengo suerte y alguno entiende el porqueestoy ya en la etapa final de mi proyecto fin de carrera y las estoy pasando canutas...

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: A mí parecer el problema es que el resultado se obtiene de forma asíncrona. Cuando el método obtener rutinas "finaliza" , `firebase.get()` estará trabajando en otro hilo, y solo serás consciente de que obtienes el resultado en el listener. ¿Qué problema habría en realizar "lo que tengas que hacer con el resultado" dentro del listener? Mejor dicho, ¿Que necesitas hacer con la lista fuera del listener?

Comment: La idea es una vez que tenga los datos almacenados en el array, mostrar ese array en un recyclerview.
Leere haber como capturar el evento de que se ha obtenido el resultado, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitas aislar el ArrayList para ir validando procesos y encontrar la falla.
Es probable que estén reinicializando el ArrayList en alguna parte.

```
private void reporta(ArrayList lista) {
   System.out.println("lista.size="+lista.size());
   //o puedes usar logger para reportar mejor
}

private void obtenerRutinas() {
   rutinasRef
          .get()
          .addOnCompleteListener((task)-> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               /*
                 Aquí vamos a crear una lista aislada para ver si este método está funcionando
                 bien, y si reporta la lista al terminar como debiera ser.
               */
               final ArrayList listaAislada = new ArrayList();
               for (QueryDocumentSnapshot rutinas : task.getResult()) {
                  /// etc etc
                  listaAislada.add(rutina);
               }
               reporta(listaAislada);
            });
}
```

Al ejecutar con estos cambios puedes ir aislando lo que si funciona

Comment: He comprobado poner el .size cada vez que añade y parece ser que lo añade ya que va incrementando el tamaño.
Pero he añadido un while en forma de semadoro para que se quede esperando a que el task acabe  y la ponga a true  pero aun asi muestra que hay 0 elementos en el array.
Otra cosa que veo rara es que en el Log puedo ver que muestra varias veces la el mismo dato aunque lo añade una vez.

Por cierto gracias por la ayuda :)

https://ibb.co/dbpNRC2

Comment: Juanma, ya modifiqué la respuesta, abajo viene otra forma de ver las rutinas capturadas. Espero te sirva de esta forma.

Comment: He probado eso que me has dicho pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.
Desde dentro del metodo ObtenerRutinas() puedo comprobar que el tamaño del array ha incrementado pero una vez que sale no realiza los cambios en el array declarada globalmente.
Realice otra prueba que me lo ha dejado mas claro:
tengo una variable booleana a false , llamo al metodo obtenerRutinas() y seguidamente se queda esperando en un bucle while esperando a que ese boolean se ponga a true.
Al final del metodo obtenerRutinas pongo la variable a true pero nunca llega a salir.

El tiene que estar que aunque

Comment: https://ibb.co/gmV5rWm

Comment: hice cambio Juanma

Comment: Eso que hiciste lo hice ya , mostraba todo correctamente, en el obtenerRutinas se obtienen los datos y desde el mismo método puedo mostrar que el array contiene los datos, pero lo que veo es que el array dispone de los datos solo dentro del método , otra cosa que me tiene mosca es que desde dentro del método  intento cambiar el valor de una variable global boleada y no lo hace...

Comment: Como comentó otro compañero, debes estar corriendo en hilos separados. Una solución es que le des el control al método obtenerRutinas(), por ejemplo cambiarlo por obtenerRutinasYContinuarElProceso(). De esta forma tu programa continúa ya con los datos generados. Otra opción es que el método obtenerRutinas() genere un evento o aviso cuando termine, y que tu programa pueda continuar. Puedes poner más código para entender mejor el esquema.